# Query to find specific value based on two parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| Column1  | Column2 | Column3 |
+----------+---------+---------+
|    1234. |    234. | No      |
|    1234. |    456. | Yes     |
|    1234. |    789. | No      |
|    3214. |    123. | No      |
|    3214. |    345. | No      |
|    3214. |    679. | No      |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

Column 1 has main ids for which there are certain sub ids which is in column 2 , I need to find if each main id has at least one yes value in column 3. Or find main ids without any yes value.

Comment: `SELECT <column1> FROM <tableName> WHERE <column3> = ‘Yes’`

Comment: Am little confused, as per your explanation, every time you want all the mainid's

Comment: @Brien - Am confused because of this *Or find main ids without any yes value* This means he even wants the MainId's when there is no `Yes`

Comment: thank you, but column 2 should play a important role here each id in column 1 will have 3 different ids which is column 2 and the value for column 2 is column 3 which will be either yes or no, iam looking for data where column 2 should atleast have one yes

Comment: so in simple language i need to pull in the data which should look like 1234.           456.           Yes , if you guys look closely 1243 is repeated but column2 has unique ids which has either yes or no values in it, so i need the data where the data needs to be in this format(1234.           456.           Yes)

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Is this for SQL Server or MySQL????  Can't be both.

Comment: @venkyps Please see my updated answer which I think resolves all your questions.

Comment: @venkyps Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Simple `select` query should work for your case

```
select distinct Column1 
from yourtable
group by Column1 
having count(case when Column3 = 'Yes' then 1 end) > 0 
    or count(case when Column3 <> 'Yes' then 1 end) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
select distinct Column1 
from yourtable
where Column3 = 'Yes'
union
select distinct Column1 
from yourtable
where Column3 = 'No'
```

Comment: Thank you for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Per your Question remarks and your most recent comment, I think the following 3 results should solve your problem (includes the code to reproduce your example table).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableName](
    [MainID] [VARCHAR] (10) NULL,
    [SubID] [VARCHAR] (10) CONSTRAINT pk_tableName_sid PRIMARY KEY,
    [Column3] [VARCHAR] (10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tableName]
SELECT '1234.','234.','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '1234.','456.','Yes' UNION ALL
SELECT '1234.','789.','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '3214.','123.','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '3214.','345.','No' UNION ALL
SELECT '3214.','679.','No' 
GO

--verify table data
--SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tableName]

--Per your Question: "I need to find if each main id has at least one yes value in column 3"
SELECT DISTINCT [MainID] AS 'MainIDs with at least one yes'
FROM [dbo].[tableName]
WHERE Column3 = 'Yes'

--Per your Question: "Or find main ids without any yes value."
SELECT DISTINCT [MainID] AS 'MainIDs without any yes value'
FROM [dbo].[tableName] 
WHERE [MainID] NOT IN (SELECT [MainID] FROM [dbo].[tableName] WHERE [Column3] = 'Yes')

--Per your comment: "so i need the data where the data needs to be in this format(1234. 456. Yes)"
SELECT DISTINCT '(' + [MainID] + ' ' + [SubID] + ' ' + [Column3] + ')' AS 'where the data needs to be in this format'
FROM [dbo].[tableName]
WHERE Column3 = 'Yes'
```

[image: Results]

The first result set identifies the `MainID` that has a corresponding `'Yes'` value.

The second result set identifies only those `MainID`'s where there are no corresponding `'Yes'` values.

The third result set is based on your comment requesting the data in a very specific format.

Example if you would like to run it yourself: http://rextester.com/NUCF30131

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you for the query.

Comment: @venkyps if one of these answers helped resolve your question, please mark one as Accepted :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column3=yes;
```

and same for no

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column3=no;
```

if you want merge then use UNION between queries

Comment: Thank you for the query.